# Две базы данных одного проекта, уместно ли?

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, json

Столкнулся с проблемой хранения данных приложения.

Есть WEB (написанная на PHP) версия и должна быть версия для windows / android (React Native).

В версии для win и android будет использоваться json база данных, в web частично mysql и json.
JSON в любом случаи понадобится, чтобы отдавать его мобильному и десктопному приложению, но возник вопрос оптимизации. Уместно ли работать с прямыми файлами .json на сервере или же лучше записывать все данные в mysql и после конвертировать их в json формат для приложения?

Comment: А что вам надо делать с этими данными? База данных позволит легко производить их обработку (сортировку, фильтрацию, преобразование) на сервере перед тем, как отдать в приложение.

Comment: @КириллМалышев я это понимаю, здесь вопрос оптимизации.
Как будет лучше, генерировать файлы .json и работать с ними (некая локальная база данных), либо же просто конвертировать базу данных в json формат.

Обращения к БД будут постоянные и ей необходимо будет обрабатывать большое количество данных (более 1,000 запросов в секунду).

Comment: Уместнее будет конвертировать данные в JSON, нежели чем хранить их в этом формате. Как вы будете делать запросы к JSON объектам?

Comment: MySQL имеет достаточно средств для работы с JSON, особенно последние версии. А "json-база данных" - это сказки, это вообще не БД.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Начнем с того, что json это такое удобное представление данных, типа массивов с ключами и значенимями с которыми хорошо работает как фронт так и бэк.
Кроме того есть уже куча вариантов баз которые так же нативно воспринимают json.

Вопрос ваш звучит не верно хотя-бы потому, что на этапе проектирования приложения вы уже столкнулись с трудностями выбора как хранилища так и представления.

Возможно вам надо подумать сначала о функциях приложения, рассчитать варианты даже минимальные поиска данных и тогда вы сразу поймете где вам хранить их в файле или в реляционной базе данных, или в хранилище типа Redis.

В общем тут вам никто не подскажет как лучше. Просто учтите, что JSON это просто один из форматов представленя структуриованных данных.

И самый важный вопрос который в заголовке:

Уместно, и это нормально, когда большие приложения работают с распределенными базами данных. Важно просто грамотно компоновать эти самые данные.